# Why are the LeQuint Dickey Mining Co. workers Australian?

Tags: django-unchained

Call me ignorant to history but after another viewing of Django, it made me question how and why, did these Australians get mixed up in pre-civil war era America?

Just going by the geography itself, its a bit of a far stretch as they would have to land essentially in Mexico or California at the time and then traveled across the south to Mississippi to start their company (assuming, of course, it is in Mississippi as that is where the last bit of the movie occurs).

Comment: They are actually suppose to be south African, which is where many mining companies were located.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.pedestrian.tv/news/entertainment/tarantino-talks-about-playing-an-aussie-in-django-/acc7caef-70cc-4967-ad5c-91cbff27984c.htm)  Tarantino is a big fan of Australian exploitation cinema and wanted to work with actors from 70s Australian cinema because he thought it would be "cool." The characters were written as indentured servants - the mining company payed their way over from Australia years before and they are working for the mining company to "pay off" their passage. You can find more about how the scene worked before being edited out [here](http://blogs.indiewire.com/theplaylist/from-script-to-screen-the-12-biggest-deleted-unfilmed-scenes-from-django-unchained-20130417?page=2#).

Comment: The scene with the Australian actors was actually shot in Australia!